# How to get id from chart?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am realy stuck. I have angular 10 application.

And I try to pas the id from a endpoint.

I have a button and that opens a popup. in that popup you have a icon. And if a user clicks on that icon a chart will be generated. And I want to have the id of that chart.

So this is the button:

```
 (click)="
  createChartFromMap(
    'line-chart',
    selectedSensor.properties['key'],
    selectedSensor.properties['name'],
    selectedSensor.properties['id']
  )"
```

and that triggers this method:

```
  createChartFromMap(element: string, node: string, name: string, id:number) {
    const chartParams: ChartParams = new ChartParamsObj(
      node,
      new Date(),
      new Date(),
      'P1D',
      'auto',
      'auto',
      id
    );
```

and this is the enpoint for the chart:

```
  id:number;
 this.sensorNodeService.cameraDataInInterval(this.id, '2021-01-21 00:00:00', '2021-01-21 23:59:59', '1').subscribe(data => {
      console.log('data',  data);
    })
```

but the id stays undefined or null.

So what I have to change? Or what I have to post here more?

Thank you

```
createChartFromMap(element: string, node: string, name: string, id:number) {

    this.sensorNodeService.cameraDataInInterval(this.id, '2021-01-21 0:00:00', '2021-01-21 23:59:59', '1').subscribe(data => {
      console.log('data',  data);
    })
    const chartParams: ChartParams = new ChartParamsObj(
      node,
      new Date(),
      new Date(),
      'P1D',
      'auto',
      'auto',
      id
    );

    

    const el = {
      config: {
        label: `${name}`
      },
      type: element,
      paramObj: chartParams
    };

    this.mapRegistryService.components.loadComponent(el.type, el.config, el.paramObj);
  }
```

This is the object passed from the api call:

```
export interface CameraNodeValue { 
    readonly id?: number;
    readonly dt?: string;
    readonly countUp?: number;
    readonly countDown?: number;
}
```

Comment: How are they related? Where is `this.sensorNodeService.cameraDataInInterval()` triggered? Please show more info.

Comment: For now I do it in the function with the button click

Comment: But if I hardcode a number, then it works

Comment: It would be easier to have a look at the problem if you provided a
[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
You can set one up over at [stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com).

Comment: this.sensorNodeService
      .cameraDataInInterval(16, '2021-01-21 00:00:00', '2021-01-21 23:59:59', '1')
      .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log('data', data);
      });  that works

Comment: "This is the object passed from the api call:" - which API call?

Comment: Do you get any `data` logged?

Comment: Hey, I've got a working minimalistic example for your case. 
Please check it out: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mat-dialog

Comment: Hi, Yes, I have seen it. But it is much more